# RoR - Devise - Sign out error - wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to implement Devise in an existing Rails3 project. I've created the users table and its in the routes and model. I'm able to create an account, and sign in, but if I go to /users/sign_out then it throws an error:

```
ArgumentError in Devise/sessionsController#destroy
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

The top part of the framework trace has:

```
devise (1.2.1) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:21:in `signed_in?'
devise (1.2.1) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:21:in `destroy'
```

My user model has the following it in:

```
# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and 
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

I'm not sure where I should be looking for adding/removing arguments for the sign_out action. Any help would be appreciated.

I looked at line 21 and it has the following:

```
def destroy
  signed_in = signed_in?(resource_name)
  Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
  ...
end
```

[source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb)

So is this a Devise bug? Or am I not setting something up right?

Comment: whats in your sessions_controller line 21?

Comment: What does your Devise.setup.... code look like?

Comment: @james The only thing I changed in devise.rb was adding config.omniauth :twitter… and one for :facebook. Even if I comment them out it still throws the error.

Comment: @corroded - do I have access to Devise's sessions_controller (it isn't in my controller dir)

Comment: it says the error is in app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb line 21. what is in the code in that file

Comment: As far as my understanding is, because Devise is rack middle ware, it is able to make it look like the code is in my controllers directory even when it is not. I do not have a devise folder in my app/controllers directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. This post helped me : https://github.com/kristianmandrup/cream/issues/24,

What I did was set `config.sign_out_all_scopes = false`, in `config/initializers/devise.rb` file. By default this config is true.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.  In my case it was because I had defined signed_in? as a helper method from a previous experiment with authentication.  Once I stripped out my former session management helper methods everything worked.